# Why I have to put @angular/common pipes in the providers array?

Tags: angular

I don't understand why I have to put @angular/common pipes(DatePipe, JsonPipe, etc..) in the providers array. Providers array is not only for the services?

```
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [JsonPipe]
})
```

Why I cant use declarations array? With custom pipes this works. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: what makes you think that you have to do that?

Comment: It doesn't' work other way.

Comment: what does not work other way?

Comment: If I don't add these pipes on providers array it shows me this message "staticinjector error no provider for pipe".

Comment: My question is why I have to add these pipes in providers array and not the custom pipe(coded by me).

Comment: I know it wroks this way, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to import CommonModule:

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      CommonModule
  ]
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing that error is because you have directly imported the JSON pipe into your Typescript component. Remove the direct import statement for the JSON pipe and it should solve your problem. You shouldn't be required to add Angular's built in Pipes to your providers array.

Answer (score 0):

We have to put pipes from `@angular/common` (and all other pipes) in the `providers` array in our module only if we are using them in the `.ts` component file injected as an injected dependency in the constructor, like this:

`constructor(private jsonPipe: JsonPipe) {}`

But if instead we are instantiating a new pipe object inside out `.ts` file than no need to add the pipe to the `providers` array. Like this:

`private jsonPipe = new JsonPipe();`